# Is it safe to mount a wire bracket to a hitch?

Tags: towing

I recently installed a Curt hitch on my jeep wrangler.  It is perfect, but I want to mount a 7-pin wiring harness via drop-down bracket.  Is it safe to drill and tap the main bar that goes across the back of the jeep?  I feel like it is sort of sketchy to drill the main bar for the hitch, but if I fill the holes with hardened bolts (probably 1/4-20) would this still be safe to tow with at the maximum capacity (4000lbf)?

Comment: Why not get one of the brackets that fits between the towball and the hitch bar? That would save drilling any new holes - something like this: http://www.towsure.com/product/Double_Sided_Twin_Towbar_Electric_Socket_Mounting_Plate

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the Curt hitch looks like on your Jeep, it's capacities, or anything like that.

But, if the hitch is made of 2-inch square tubing, you can safely drill a 1/4-20 hole in it.

Drill through the center of the square tubing, though - don't try to get crazy and drill long ways through a full side of the tubing. That would obviously compromise the strength of your tubing.

If you plan to keep the Jeep and hitch for a long time, hitting the exposed metal parts with a little bit of paint will prevent it from rusting faster than normal.